# Problem splitting matix eqations in align environment

Tags: alignat

I am trying to get my equation to appear like this:
[image]
however, I am having a problem getting my program to compile properly using this `alignat` environment.  Can you please help my get the equation to show up properly.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
{\mathbf{u}} & = H^{-1}({\mathbf{P}}_{T}-B) \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{split}
&\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}\right.\\
& \left. - X \right)
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to split a `\left( ... \right)` construct across lines -- not allowed.

Comment: Hello @Micro.  I tried to modify the code based on the link that you sent me to (please see modified code in question), however, I still am having a problem getting the code to compile.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you can't split up `\left` and `\right` across line breaks or `&` divisions.  each `\left ... \right` pair has to be complete within a "cell".  if you have need of an unmatched pair, match the "real" one with an empty delimiter -- `\left.` or `\right.` (in the proper order).  if one of the lines doesn't have the same height, then you will need a `\vphantom` to stretch it; there are quite a few questions that address that situation, including the cited one.

Comment: Hello,  I keep getting the error now ''Extra }, or forgotten \right.<template> } $\endtemplate.  I looked at the examples but still not sure of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Even after the edit, there's still `\left(` on one line and `\right)` on the following line. Why would this work now, given that it didn't work earlier?

Comment: A separate issue: the linebreak before `-X` seems unnecessary. What are you trying to achieve with the linebreak?

Comment: Hello @Mico, X is actually another matrix, but the code was getting convoluted so I just put X in its place.  I have modified the question code with the `\right.` and `\left.` but I am still unsuccessful in the compilation.

Comment: Hello,  I moved the `&` and it compiles now but it does not look right.  Can you help to fix it to show like the figure above? Thanks.